# How to enforce creation of singletons by a Kotlin interface

Tags: kotlin

I would like to create an interface that enforces each implementation of it to be a singleton:

```
interface MyInterface {
    val myValue: Int
}
```

```
object MySingleton: MyInterface {
    override val myValue: String = "My value"
}
```

However, with the above interface I can also create a class as follows:

```
class NotMySingleton: MyInterface {
    override val myValue: String = "My value"
}
```

How would I go about enforcing such a rule within `MyInterface`?

Comment: That's an unusual requirement!  Can you explain anything about why you'd like this, and what it's trying to achieve?

Comment: @gidds I believe it would make it really easy to keep an organised file structure as well as ensure each implementation is essentially static. Makes it even nicer when you consider I have to pass and store those implementations around a lot - as func arguments, in sets etc. - doing so without having to instantiate them (since they are singletons) or provide calls such as `class.instance` using companion objects is much easier. It's not actually a necessity to have this enforcement - but I thought it would be quite nice to!

Comment: @KacperFloriański, I don't believe it's possible to have it as compile-time enforcement. However, it's possible to have a test that scans the classpath for every descendent of `MyInterface` and insures that it's a singleton using reflection.